# AppxManifest.xml re -adding lines of code after project build/rebuild

Tags: xml, visual-studio, uwp, win-universal-app

The following are the lines of code that are somehow magically and Automatically added to the appxmanifest file  after project build.Im getting errors and i cannot get rid of those lines. I **delete** them ,**save** , **clean** , **build** and they are **still** getting added. Any thought or opinion of how to fix this MS bug?

```
 <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="mp3">
            <uap:Logo>images\icon.png</uap:Logo>
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.mp3</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap:Extension>
      </Extensions>
      <build:Metadata>
        <build:Item Name="TargetFrameworkMoniker" Value=".NETCore,Version=v5.0" />
        <build:Item Name="VisualStudio" Version="14.0" />
        <build:Item Name="VisualStudioEdition" Value="Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015" />
        <build:Item Name="OperatingSystem" Version="10.0.15063.0 (WinBuild.160101.0800)" />
        <build:Item Name="Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.dll" Version="14.0.25431.1" />
        <build:Item Name="ProjectGUID" Value="{EB37D9F2-CC77-4211-8C86-80029116E87C}" />
        <build:Item Name="OptimizingToolset" Value="None" />
        <build:Item Name="TargetRuntime" Value="Managed" />
        <build:Item Name="Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks.dll" Version="14.0.25527.1" />
        <build:Item Name="MakePri.exe" Version="10.0.14393.33 (rs1_release_sec.160727-1952)" />
      </build:Metadata>
```

Answer (score 3):

Open the Package Manifest Editor and remove your declaration for the file type association. That should get rid if the extension. The build tag is just meta data and is ignored at build/deploy/run time.

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Comment: The build:Metadata section is a collection of info that is (to my knowledge) mostly used by the Windows Store backend to compile your application upon submission. You shouldn't ever need to edit it directly.